# Dock RStudio Source Editor

Tags: rstudio

I have undocked my RStudio Source Editor (the place where I write my code).  I can't find a way to redock the editor -- making it difficult to program as I have to switch back and forth between the main application and my code.  Is there anyway to redock this window?

Comment: try opening a blank source script in the "main" window. you should then be able to drag your "tab" next to this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the icon in the floating window...

[image]

The one with the arrow